# Javascript will not execute with PNGEncoder

Tags: batik

I am trying to use the PNGEncoder class in batik to convert svg files to png format.
My code pretty much comes from the example given on the apache site.

```
public void writePng(String pngPath) throws Exception{
        String parentPath=FileUtils.getParentPath(pngPath);
        FileUtils.mkdirs(parentPath);
    PNGTranscoder t = new PNGTranscoder();
    t.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_EXECUTE_ONLOAD,new Boolean(true));

    FileInputStream iStream=new FileInputStream(svgPath);
    TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(iStream);

    OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(pngPath);
    TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);

    t.transcode(input, output);

    ostream.flush();
    ostream.close();        
    }
```

An snippet of the input svg with embedded javascript is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" height="600" version="1.2" width="800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs/>
    <script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="file:/D:/dev/svn/deathstar/xfltoalsxml/src/js/helper_functions.js"/>
    <script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="file:/D:/dev/svn/deathstar/xfltoalsxml/src/js/textFlow.js"/>
            <text id="defid_text_1" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 269.9 57)"/>
            <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[var textNode = document.getElementById('defid_text_1');
textNode.setAttributeNS(null,'x',0);
textNode.setAttributeNS(null,'y',0);
textNode.setAttributeNS(null,'font-size',18);
textNode.setAttributeNS(null,'font-family','ArialMT');
document.documentElement.appendChild(textNode);
 textFlow('testdata abcd ',textNode,514.1,0,20,false);
]]></script>
</svg>
```

Whenever I try to run my writePng function I get the exception

```
ava.lang.Exception: Unknown language: text/ecmascript
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeContext.getInterpreter(BridgeContext.java:575)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.BaseScriptingEnvironment.getInterpreter(BaseScriptingEnvironment.java:289)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.BaseScriptingEnvironment.loadScripts(BaseScriptingEnvironment.java:404)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:214)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder.transcode(ImageTranscoder.java:92)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(XMLAbstractTranscoder.java:142)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:156)
    at com.amered.xfltojs.app.FrameToSvg.writePng(FrameToSvg.java:156)
    at com.amered.xfltojs.app.DocData.generateImageData(DocData.java:172)
```

The files display properly when using squiggle.

I have checked everywhere I can think of and can find no explanation for why this is happening.
Hopefully someone has some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same exception. For some reason, this worked for me:

Instead of

```
TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(new FileReader("myfile.svg"));
```

I use

```
String file = new File("myfile.svg").toURI().toString();
TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(file);
```